# How to trigger a Runnable from IRQ

Tags: autosar

Inagine the following use-case:
If a specific interrupt occurred, you want to trigger a Runnable from within this IRQ and then exit the interrupt in order to keep it as short as possible. Furthermore this Runnable might also have to be triggered with a specific delay after the IRQ occurred.
In both cases you can define an alarm that triggers the Runnable though an event.
The problem is that such a thing is not supported by the configuration tools. The only way to somehow configure this is to create dummy RPorts that triggers the Runnable on-data-receive and to mis-use the generated Alarm+Event in the IRQ.
Or is there a better approach to trigger Runnables from IRQ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the principal of AUTOSAR is also abstraction of HW.

SWCs are run above the RTE. Therefore, their access are limited.
MCAL is used to abstract the common HW. HwAbstraction above MCAL is used to abstract them further up the layers.

A driver can provide notification to higher layers. 
These notifications can then be mapped to Events (e.g. Internal/ExternalTriggerOccuredEvent, DataReceivedEvent, DataReceiveErrorEvent, ...).

So, the question is, what the purpose of the interrupt is, and why you should have a runnable above the RTE react on them.

e.g. the ISR for RxIndications for incoming message, or the TxConfirmation for successful transmission of a message. The interrupts are handled in Can driver (Can_Irq).
Can driver has a configurable option for CanRxProcessing and CanTxProcessing. If INTTERRUPT, the callbacks to higher layers are called directly within the ISR. If POLLING, the Can drivers is polling this from Can_Mainfunction_Read() or Can_Mainfunction_Write() on Task Level.
The higher layers (e.g. Com) also has options, e.g. ComIpduProcessing DEFERRED or IMMEDIATE. This means, that all configured callouts are called immediately (in the context of the lower layer processing config INTERRUPT or POLLING) or deferred on task level within Com__Mainfunction_Rx() or Com_Mainfunction_Tx().

These callbacks are configured by RTE to go to a specific port / runnable, due to dataReceivedEvent, dataWrite/SendCompletedEvent.

You could also create a CDD to implement a specific HW abstraction 
 / driver implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I understand all you said and everything is correct. But unfortunately it does not answer my problem/question.
As you mention, Runnables are triggered by events through Internal/ExternalTriggerOccuredEvent, DataReceivedEvent, DataReceiveErrorEvent, ...
But in case you have an external device (chip) that creates an interrupt (let's say, if new data is available) then you need to configure a dummy port (which is then unconnected) and use the generated event.
As far as I can see, the AUTOSAR metamodel does not forsee such a trigger.

Comment: External chips / equipment should be abstracted by a driver in the HwAbstraction layer atop the MCAL. Similar things exists already in AUTOSAR like the ExtWdg or CanTrcv drivers. They abstract the external HW by e.g. existing MCAL drivers, like Port/Dio, SPI or other means (like EthTrcv to PHY). These drivers again provide an abstracted notification interface to higher layers .. e.g. Services or RTE. That's why I showed this by the CAN reception/transmission, with DataReceivedEvent. But you could also use a TriggerEvent (internal/External). If you need more performance, write a Complex Driver.